# sup C = sup A + sup B?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $A$ and $B$ be sets of real numbers and write $$C=\{x+y:x\in A,y\in B\}.$$ Find a relation among $\sup A$, $\sup B$, and $\sup C$.

**My attempt:**

I'm assuming the answer is $\sup C=\sup A+\sup B$.

$x\le \sup A\ \forall x\in A$

$y\le \sup B\ \forall y\in B$

$\implies x+y\le \sup A+\sup B$ $\forall x\in A,\ y\in B$

So, $\sup A+\sup B$ is an upper bound for $C$.

Suppose $\sup C\neq\sup A+\sup B$.

$\implies \exists l<\sup A+\sup B$ such that $x+y\le l$ $\forall x\in A,\ y\in B$

$\implies x\le l-y\ \forall x\in A,\ y\in B$

So, $l-y$ is an upper bound of $A\ \forall y\in B$

I feel that I'm on the right track but I don't know how to get a contradiction. Any suggestions?

Comment: What is $\inf \{ l - y : y \in B\}$?

Comment: I think it would be $l-\sup B$. How does that help?

Comment: Is it also an upper bound for $A$?

Comment: Yes. I said that in my post.

Comment: You only said explicitly that $l-y$ is an upper bound for each $y$. But you seem to know that that implies $\inf \{ l - y : y \in B\}$ is also an upper bound for $A$. Well, then $\sup A \leqslant \inf \{ l - y : y \in B\}$.

Comment: So $\sup A\le l-\sup B\implies \sup A+\sup B\le l<\sup A+\sup B$ - contradiction! Correct?

Comment: Yes, but only if nothing like $+\infty + (-\infty)$ occurs anywhere. If e.g. $\sup A = +\infty$ and $B = \varnothing$, this breaks. It's generally a good idea to treat the special cases (one or both sets empty, one or both unbounded from above) separately, and then take care of the regular case that both sets are nonempty and bounded from above.

Answer (score 3):

This is another approach for your reference:

After getting $\sup A+\sup B$ is an upper bound of $C$, let $\epsilon>0$, then $\epsilon/2>0$. Hence there exist some $x'\in A$, $y'\in B$ such that $$x'+\epsilon/2>\sup A\text{ and }y'+\epsilon/2>\sup B$$
$$\Rightarrow x'+y'+\epsilon>\sup A+\sup B$$
It follows that $\sup C=\sup A+\sup B$.

Comment: I think there's a mistake in your answer. Shouldn't it be $x'+\epsilon/2>\sup A\text{ and }y'+\epsilon/2>\sup B$ and $x'+y'+\epsilon>\sup A+\sup B$ ?

Comment: @Nimantha Yes you are correct. thank you for spotting out this

Answer (score 2):

If $z\in C$ then $x\in A$ and $y\in B$ exist with $z=x+y$ so that:$$z=x+y\leq\sup A+\sup B$$

This justifies the conclusion that: $$\sup C\leq\sup A+\sup B$$

Conversely if $r<\sup A+\sup B$ then you can write $r=r_1+r_2$ with $r_1<\sup A$ and $r_2<\sup B$.

So elements $x\in A$ and $y\in B$ exist with $r_1<x$ and $r_2<y$ and consequently: $$r=r_1+r_2\leq x+y\leq\sup C$$

This justifies the conclusion that: $$\sup A+\sup B\leq\sup C$$

Comment: Could you please explain this line? "Conversely if $r<\sup A+\sup B$ then you can write $r=r_1+r_2$ with $r_1<\sup A$ and $r_2<\sup B$."

Comment: If $r<a+b$ then $r=a+c$ where $c<b$ right? Some $\epsilon>0$ will exist with $c+\epsilon<b$. Then $r=r_1+r_2$ where $r_1=a-\epsilon<a$ and $r_2=c+\epsilon<b$